why application logs are not being rotated in non leader nodes in hashicorp vault?
I'm using hashicorp with integrated storage and 5 nodes.
Once a node becomes a leader everything is ok with the application log rotation, but once a another node become a leader then the logs stop rotating on that instance. Is it the default behavior? is there a way to solve it?
basically the configuration bellow is the only configs i have in my vault.hcl file
log_level = "trace"
log_file = "{{vault_base_path}}/logs"
log_rotate_max_files = "30"


Have you been able to confirm that the same log-related config exists in all of the vault.hcl files across all nodes in your cluster?

@Zam yes it exists in all the nodes
